# $X-A\subset\overline{X-\operatorname{Int}(A)}$ is true or false?

Tags: general-topology

Here $A$ is a proper subset of the topological space $X$, not necessarily an open subset.

If it's true, I know that

$$\overline{X-\operatorname{Int}(A)}=\left(X-\operatorname{Int}(A)\right)\cup\left(X-\operatorname{Int}(A)\right)' $$

But I don't know where to go from here. Also, I couldn't think of a counter-example to show it's false.

Comment: It is of course always true that $S\subseteq \overline S$ in topology.  So it would be a good idea to state the problem in the body of your Question (not only in the title) to make clear whether you are asking if the inclusion is always *proper*.

Comment: @hardmath But this problem can't be reduced to $S \subset \overline{S}$ when $\text{Int}(A) \ne A$.

Comment: Since $\mathring{\mathrm{A}} \subset \mathrm{A},$ it follows that $\mathrm{X} - \mathrm{A} \subset \mathrm{X} - \mathring{\mathrm{A}}$ and with stronger reasons, $\mathrm{X} - \mathrm{A} \subset \overline{\mathrm{X} - \mathring{\mathrm{A}}}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M \subset N$ then $X\setminus N\subset X\setminus M$.

> Pf: just element chase.  If $a\in X\setminus N$ then$a\in X$ but $x\not \in N$ so $x \not\in M \subset N$.  So $x \in X\setminus M$

So $Int(A)\subset A$ so

$X\setminus A \subset X\setminus Int(A)\subset \overline{X\setminus Int(A)}$.

The statement is true even if you don't actually *know* anything.